# Looking for the ttf2pt1 package

Tags: fonts, 23.10

I need to convert a `.ttf` (TrueType font) file to `.pfa` format and according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676342/generating-afm-from-ttf I need `ttf2pt1`. However when I try to install it under Ubuntu 23.10 I get:

```
master >sudo apt-get install ttf2pt1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package ttf2pt1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `apt-cache search ttf`.

Comment: linux has no such converter.  you are best to go online to...  https://everythingfonts.com/ttf-to-pfa

Comment: Within the package sources of all supported Ubuntu releases there is neither a package called "ttf2pt1" nor a package which holes a file named "ttf2pt1".

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the `ttf2pt1` package has been superseded by `ttf2ufm`, which provides the same functionality. See [ttf2ufm](https://github.com/PhenX/ttf2ufm) for more details.